# Ruby on Rails bundle install mysql2 error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**About**

Currently, I`m building the Ruby on Rails project environment.
However, if I implement bundle install, the following error occurs.
I do not know where the cause is, I would like advice.

**Environment**

- Ruby v2.5.3
- Rails 5.2.2
- MySQL 5.7

**Run Command 1**

`$ bundle install`

**Output error**

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
/Users/xxx/project_dir/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/CHANGELOG.md
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**Run Command 2**

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

**Output error**

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190220-84910-2gf7i1.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib
-----
creating Makefile
current directory: /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that some system libraries are missing. As far as I understand you are using macos. So please try: `xcode-select --install` and `bundle install`

**UPDATE**
We had a private chat with @getty and we came up a solution. The problem was with some missing headers regarding to ruby program. 
So we fixed the problem like following:

1. rbenv uninstall 2.5.3
2. CC=gcc rbenv install 2.5.3
3. rbenv local 2.5.3
4. bundle install

This solution would be applied to rvm or other version managers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you say, I am using MacOS. Command execution result `xcode-select --install`  -> `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`,  `bundle install` -> same result as above

Comment: Ok let's do the second workaround :) 
1 -> `brew install openssl`
2 -> `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/`

Comment: let me know if the second work around does not work. I have some other toys :)

Comment: Thank you. `brew install openssl` -> `openssl 1.0.2q is already installed and up-to-date`, `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/` -> `bundle install` -> It`s same :)

Comment: `bundle config --global build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"` and then `bundle install`

Comment: bundle config --global build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)” ->
`Your application has set build.mysql2 to "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include". This will override the global value you are currently setting`, bundle install -> It`s same :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188736/discussion-between-getty-and-zeitnot).

Comment: I think the problem is related to mojave. I mean you upgraded your OS but other softwares were not updated. So please reinstall mysql again.

Comment: BTW, I am in the chat room.